# Calling refresh on another grid after removal

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I currently have `firstGrid` that has some records, I have set a warning on removal message so a dialog box pops up when I click the delete button. How do I make it so `secondGrid`  refresh when I confirm the delete on `firstGrid`?

```
firstGrid.setWarnOnRemoval(true);
firstGrid.setWarnOnRemovalMessage("Delete?");
```

Answer (score 1):

SmartGwt doesn't support a customized behavior for this operation. You should program it by yourself.

Just create a new ListGridField and refresh your second grid in the CallBack after the remove operation. Your first approach could be the following:

```
ListGridField removeListGridField = new ListGridField("removeButton", 20);

removeListGridField.setType(ListGridFieldType.ICON);
removeListGridField.setCellIcon("[SKIN]actions/remove.png");
removeListGridField.setCanEdit(false);
removeListGridField.setCanFilter(false);
removeListGridField.setCanGroupBy(false);
removeListGridField.setCanSort(false);
removeListGridField.setCanDragResize(false);
removeListGridField.setCanFreeze(false);
removeListGridField.setCanHide(false);

removeListGridField.addRecordClickHandler(new RecordClickHandler()
{
    @Override
    public void onRecordClick(RecordClickEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getRecord() == null) // local record
            {
                discardEdits(event.getRecordNum(), 0);
                yourGrid.fetchData();
            }
            else
                removeData(event.getRecord(), new DSCallback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(DSResponse dsResponse, Object data, DSRequest dsRequest)
                    {
                        yourGrid.fetchData();
                    }
                });
    }
});
```